# C++ File - MS Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, file

I am making a C++ program that writes data to a file.
I am using MS Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop,and my sources and .exe file are in different folders.
So,I need to create two files - one in sources folder and one in .exe-s folder.
But then,if I run my program using compiler,it will write data to the file in sources folder,and if I run .exe file,it will write to it's folder.
But I want all the data to be stored in the same file.
Sorry for bad explanation...
Please help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can change working directory in `Project properties -> Debugging -> Working directory`. Set it to `$(TargetDir)` (it's a macro for `Output Directory` which can be set up at `General`).

This way, when you starting program in VS, all relative paths will begin in binary's directory (instead of project directory, as it was with `$(ProjectDir)`).